# How to listen to certain action in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using React and Redux (react starter kit).

I have a set of action, and when some are called, I want to dispatch side effects.

For exemple, I have a workspace that contains projects, if workspaceID in the store change, (using my action setWorkspaceId) then, the projects store will notice the change, and start execute some api call to update itself.

IN angular/ngrx, I was using Effects, so the Effect where dispatching other action when a certain action was called.

What is the redux way ? I was checking into Redux-Saga, but is there something else or already built in ?

Comment: No there is nothing built in. But there are different solutions. Redux-Saga is one of them. I recommend you checking redux thunk. It is simpler  and better for small apps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Left alone, Redux just accumulates state from the actions it receives via `dispatch`, so there is no single Redux-blessed way to trigger side effects from actions.

But it supports [middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware#understanding-middleware), which allows you to monitor, subscribe to and even change actions that are dispatched.

If you're familiar with RxJS via ngrx, [`redux-observable`](https://redux-observable.js.org/) might be something worth looking into. It allows you to consume and emit actions via RxJS's observable type. The use case you describe of triggering an API call when a value changes would be well-suited to this.

But as you say, there's also `redux-saga`, which uses generators to model asynchronous logic around the consumption and production of Redux actions and other side effects. There are pros and cons to these and [all the other solutions](https://github.com/brillout/awesome-redux#side-effects) out there.

Ultimately I suggest starting with what's most familiar to you, especially if you're new to Redux.

One piece of unsolicited advice - middleware is easy to overuse. Be wary of doing in middleware and side effects that which can be achieved in a reducer.

It's easy and tempting enough to set up middleware to dispatch action B in response to action A, but if all action B does is update some state, maybe that state's reducer can just react to action A.

Comment: Thank you, I really like the `redux-observable`. Will try to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the redux way?

Use [`mapStateToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops-object) to subscribe for store changes.

Then use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) in your function component, with `workspaceID` as dependency, to do some side effects (i.e calling an api).

```
function Component(props) {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      // call api
    }
    , [props.workspaceID] // only run effect when workspaceID changes
  )
}

mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    workspaceID: state.workspaceID // subscribe to workspaceID changes in store
  }
}

connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Component)
```

Comment: Thank you, But I have a question, with this implementation, iuf there are numerous component changing the workspaceId, they all have to include this code somewhere right ? Is there a way to separe the effect from the component, so It can be used anywhere ?

Comment: @Bobby unfortunately, `useEffect` should be called within the function component w/c is a [rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: @Bobby Fortunately, react has a concept of HOC ([Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)). You can create a HOC, which wraps all your components, providing the prop to them